# Combine href, click and data-bind in knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I'm trying to show some kind of loader while waiting for a slow link:

```
<a href="/api/action/that/takes/some/time" data-bind="click: showLoading">
```

```js
this.showLoading = function () {
    // Display loader while waiting for the redirect
}
```

The `click` seems to override the actual link. Is there a way to fix that?

**Clarification edit:**
I could do something like this, but I'd prefer to keep the url on the href and just add the `showLoading` bit to those links that will take some time

```
<a href="#" data-bind="click: showLoading.bind($data, '/api/action/that/takes/some/time'">

this.showLoading = function(link) {
    // Display loader while waiting for the redirect
    window.location.href = link;
};
```

Comment: Maybe get the href and redirect to it?

Comment: @Jim Yeah I was hoping that there would be some kind of `preventDefault` I could call or return something from the function to continue the execution of the href

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just need to `return true` from your `click` handler to trigger the browser's default action:

```
this.showLoading = function () {
    // Display loader while waiting for the redirect
    return true;
}
```

See it also in the documentation: [Allowing the default click action](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html#note-3-allowing-the-default-click-action)

Comment: Ok, feel pretty stupid now :) I thought I had tried that, but I probably only did `return;`...